SQL connection string error: 25 .NET on 64 bit .NET application

I'm getting (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect when trying to connect to 2019 SQL Server.
The error happens only when application runs in 64 bit mode
- Same app and same connection string runs perfect in 32 bit mode
The application is running on Windows 11 Pro 64bit

Here is the connection opening.
      var connectionString = this.textBox1.Text;
      string errConnectionString;
      try
      {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
          errConnectionString = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", sqlConnection.DataSource, sqlConnection.Database);
          sqlConnection.Open();
          MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
      }
      catch (Exception exc)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
      }


Tried to play around with connection string parameters, no success.
I guess some SQL Server package is probably missing.
Any advice?

The error you mention in your question is different from the screenshot

Does the blacked-out Data Source property refer to an ODBC Data Source name or an SQL Client Alias (e.g.: in the Client Config tool, or in SQL Server Configuration Manager)? These tools have seperate configurations for 32 bit and 64 bit processes, so is it only configured for 32 bit processes?

What is the actual connection string? And what is the actual error message?

You shouldn't be using the sa user. Create a user with only the necessary permissions.

The error message in the screenshot indicates that the server is unreachable. Your password is the only value wrapped in quotes, can you verify that this isn't the trigger for the connection issue?

Data Source is SQL server host name. It is a default instance.
The error: The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid).

The password is wrapped up in quotes, because it contains special characters. But the same connection string works without any modification in the same app, compiled with x32 configuration.
